# Connected but not path connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Define $X=\lbrace (0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|y \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$ and $Y=\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x>0, y=$sin$(\frac{1}{x})\rbrace$. Prove that $X \cup Y$ is connected but not path connected.

I know the definitions of connected and path connected spaces, but I don't know how to start with this exercise. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The idea is that while any open set containing $X$ in the plane also contains parts of $Y$, thus making the two parts connected, there is no continuous path from any point on $Y$ to any point on $X$.

Comment: This is a slightly altered version of a famous example called the topologist's sine curve, which you can find details on easily with a google search